# How to generate custom routes for some actions with FOSRESTBundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosrestbundle

I actually use automatic route generation for my api Rest, using the [FOSRESTBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), also I use [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) to generate the api doc.

To generate routes for the api this I have in my routing.yml

```
users:
    type:     rest
    resource: Project\RESTBundle\Controller\UsersController
```

But for some actions I want to set my custom routing... If I try to add another route rule for an action it simply ignore it and generate the automatic route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to declare the route with the same name right after the configuration you set. For example, the following works.

```
users:
    type:     rest
    resource: Project\RESTBundle\Controller\UsersController

get_users:
    pattern:  /api/users/customUri.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectRESTBundle:Users:indexAction, _format: json }
```